# How to use multiple alias in a plpgsql procedure in a trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I found many information about this topic, but nothing I can really utilize for my function.

I created a trigger-function in PostsgreSQL 9.6.0 which works fine when I use static variables. Anyway, because I or other people will use the script later ,I want keep it as easy as possible to adapt it on a new environment by changing needed variables in the head of the document. The structure of my function can be described with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION userinput() 
   RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$

DECLARE
tblname TEXT := 'products';
trgtcol TEXT := 'col1, col2, col4';

BEGIN
SELECT trgtcol FROM tblname;    

END;
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

How can I now set set an Alias for:

1. The name of the table `'products'` represented by the alias `tblname`?
2. A varying number of columns after the select statement?

I know the code above doesn't work but using provided declarations I expect this outcome:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col4 FROM products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL. To be safe from SQL injection, use something like this:

```
DECLARE
   tblname text := 'products';
   trgtcol text := 'col1, col2, col4';
   sanitized_col text;
BEGIN
   /* convert the columns to something safe */
   SELECT string_agg(
             quote_ident(c.name),
             ', '
          ) INTO sanitized_col
   FROM regexp_split_to_table(trgtcol, ', *') AS c(name);

   EXECUTE format('SELECT %s FROM %I', sanitized_col, tblname)
      INTO ...
END;
```